# Python Dictionary Library with list names

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

The idea is to the be able to refer to list names via dictionary
but the problem is that it's not allowing me to do so, i

```
letter_master = {
    'a': letter_a,
    'b': letter_b,
    'c': letter_c,
    'd': letter_d,
    'e': letter_e,
    'f': letter_f,
    'g': letter_g,
    'h': letter_h,
    'i': letter_i,
    'j': letter_j,
    'k': letter_k,
    'l': letter_l,
    'm': letter_m,
    'n': letter_n,
    'o': letter_o,
    'p': letter_p,
    'q': letter_q,
    'r': letter_r,
    's': letter_s,
    't': letter_t,
    'u': letter_u,
    'v': letter_v,
    'w': letter_w,
    'x': letter_x,
    'y': letter_y,
    'z': letter_z}
```

The Error Code is as follows:

```
'a': letter_a,
NameError: name 'letter_a' is not defined
```

Comment: what is letter_a?
you have to define letter_a first.

Comment: letter_a, points back to a list, in this case it points to: letter_a = ['a3', 'b2', 'b4', 'c1', 'c5', 'd1', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'f1', 'f5', 'g1', 'g5']

Comment: Where do you *define* these lists?

Comment: I defined it right below the dictionary, would that make a difference if it was the other way around?

Comment: It would make a big difference, but there is little reason to define both a dictionary variable and 26 list variables. One of the points of a dictionary is to be able to avoid repetitious code (such as creating 26 lists on 26 (or more) lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that since such things such as `letter_a` don't exist, you need to create these lists when creating the dictionary:

```
>>> letter_master = {c:[] for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'}
>>> letter_master
{'s': [], 'k': [], 'b': [], 'a': [], 'i': [], 'n': [], 'r': [], 'x': [], 'g': [], 'l': [], 'v': [], 'h': [], 'w': [], 'm': [], 'o': [], 'e': [], 'q': [], 'c': [], 't': [], 'z': [], 'f': [], 'u': [], 'y': [], 'p': [], 'j': [], 'd': []}
```

Then, you need to add code to populate these lists.

Comment: Ahh okay i see, thanks, so is it redundant to make lists outside the dictionary then have the dictionary call it to it?

Comment: Yes -- just use things such as `letter_master['a']` in place of `letter_a`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around your values. Example:

```
>>> letter_master = { 'a' : letter_a, 'b' : letter_b, 'c' : letter_c } #missing quotes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'letter_a' is not defined

>>> letter_master = { 'a' : 'letter_a', 'b' : 'letter_b', 'c' : 'letter_c' }
>>> letter_master
{'a': 'letter_a', 'b': 'letter_b', 'c': 'letter_c'}
>>> letter_master['a']
'letter_a'
```

If letter_a was an actual variable, you wouldn't get an error:

```
>>> letter_a = ['a3', 'b2', 'b4', 'c1', 'c5', 'd1', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'f1', 'f5', 'g1', 'g5']
>>> letter_master = { 'a' : letter_a, 'b' : 'letter_b', 'c' : 'letter_c' }
>>> letter_master['a']
['a3', 'b2', 'b4', 'c1', 'c5', 'd1', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'f1', 'f5', 'g1', 'g5']
```

Comment: `letter_a = ['a3', 'b2', 'b4', 'c1', 'c5', 'd1', 'd5', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'f1', 'f5', 'g1', 'g5']` is what 'a' points to, which is latter used to interate through it to get x/y coordinates